# r apply function over two lists

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply

I have two vectors. I would like to apply a function to each possible combination of these two vectors. For illustration, suppose I have the following two vectors.

```
pets <- c('dog','cat','lemur')
fruit <- c('banana','apple','papaya')
```

I want to apply a function to the following combinations of variables, and save the results of each function call along with the variable values.

```
[dog, banana]
[dog, apple]
[dog, papaya]
[cat, banana]
[cat, apple] etc...
```

What would be the neatest way of achieving this in r? It feels like it should be a job for the apply family.

Comment: Probably `expand.grid(pets, fruit)`

Comment: I see that expand.grid creates every combination of the two vectors, however I was hoping to run a function over each combination

Comment: You could try something like this `dplyr::mutate(expand.grid(pets, fruit), function_output=paste(Var1, Var2))` where `paste()` is an example function

Answer (score 2):

```
levels(interaction(pets, fruit, sep = ', '))
```

Ouput:

```
[1] "cat, apple"    "dog, apple"    "lemur, apple" 
[4] "cat, banana"   "dog, banana"   "lemur, banana"
[7] "cat, papaya"   "dog, papaya"   "lemur, papaya"
```

Comment: Hi @datavoredan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

`expand.grid` is what you want. `?expand.grid` states that:

> Create a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors or factors.

So you could do:

```
e <- expand.grid(pets, fruit)
df <- data.frame(col=apply(e,1,function(x) paste0("[",x[1],", ",x[2],"]")))
# OR if brackets are not important
# data.frame(col=apply(e,1,paste,collapse=", "))

            # col
# 1   [dog, banana]
# 2   [cat, banana]
# 3 [lemur, banana]
# 4    [dog, apple]
# 5    [cat, apple]
# 6  [lemur, apple]
# 7   [dog, papaya]
# 8   [cat, papaya]
# 9 [lemur, papaya]
```

Please note that data frame `e` already contains possible combinations of two vectors. The next line is necessary only if you want to format them.